# Database Position Index

Tags: database

Does anyone know of any databases (SQL or NoSQL) that have native support for position based indexes?

To clarify, on many occasions I've had the need to maintain a position based collection, where the order or position is maintained by an external entity (user, external service, etc). By maintained I mean the order of the items in the collection will be changed quite often but are not based on any data fields in the record, the order is completely arbitrary as far as the service maintaining the collection is concerned. The service needs to provide an interface that allows CRUD functions by position (Insert after Pos X, Delete at Pos Y, etc) as well as manipulating the position (move from pos X to pos Y).

I'm aware there are workaround ways that you can achieve this, I've implemented many myself but this seems like a pretty fundamental way to want to index data. So I can't help but feel there must be an off the shelf solution out there for this.

The only thing I've seen that comes close to this is Redis's List data type, which while it's ordered by position, is pretty limited (compared to a table with multiple indexes) and Redis is more suited as a Cache rather than a persistent data store.

Finally I'm asking this as I've got a requirement that needs user ordered collections that could contain 10,000's of records.

Comment: Postgres' arrays come to mind, but you can't really do the CRUD stuff you want on them. Although you _can_ write functions that would do that. And for integer arrays this is already available as an extension

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't know about postgres arrays, thanks for that. They are on the column so not quite an index but might be useful, I'll have a play. Was the extension [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/intarray.html)?

Comment: You _can_ index the column to speed up lookups. `intarray` provides additional operators and functions to deal with integer arrays (and only integers)

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone, the best approximation of this I've found so far is to implement a Linked List structure in a Graph Database (like Neo4J). Maintaining the item links is considerably easier than maintaining a position column (especially if you only need next links, i.e. not doubly linked). It's easier as there is no need to leave holes, re-index, etc, you only have to move pointers (or relations). The performance is pretty good but reads slow down linearly if you're trying to access items towards the end of the list by position, as you have to scan (SKIP) the whole list start to end.